# Evaluate an expression in terms other variables when lots of equations are involved

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, evaluation

Unless I misunderstood something, this is different from a [similarly worded question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179456/express-variable-in-terms-other-variables-when-lots-of-equations-are-involved) because I am not asking for the relationship between different variables here.

I want to convert an expression from one set of variables to another. For example, consider the following equations:

```
3*BP == 5*PC
9*AQ == 8*BQ
AC^2 == AB^2 + BC^2
PQ^2 == BP^2 + BQ^2
AP^2 == AB^2 + BP^2
BC == BP + PC
AB == AQ + BQ
```

This time, I want to get the value of `5*AC^4 + 4*AP^2` in terms of `BQ` and `BP`. Can this be done in Mathematica?

I will really appreciate any help on how to proceed. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you there

```
Reduce[{3*BP == 5*PC, 9*AQ == 8*BQ, AC^2 == AB^2 + BC^2, PQ^2 == BP^2 + BQ^2,
  AP^2 == AB^2 + BP^2, BC == BP + PC, AB == AQ + BQ}, {AC, AP, BQ, BP, PQ}]
```

From that you extract rules to evaluate your expression

```
5*AC^4 + 4*AP^2 //. {AC -> -(1/27) Sqrt[-2041 PC^2 + 2601 PQ^2], 
  AP -> -(1/27) Sqrt[-5200 PC^2 + 2601 PQ^2], PC -> BP*3/5,
  PQ -> 1/24 Sqrt[729 AQ^2 + 1600 PC^2], AQ -> (8 AB)/17, AB -> (17 BQ)/9}
```

which will give you

```
(*4/729 (-1872 BP^2 + 289/64 (576 BP^2 + 576 BQ^2)) + (5 (-((18369 BP^2)/25) +
  289/64 (576 BP^2 + 576 BQ^2))^2)/531441*)

Simplify[%]

(*(4096 BP^4)/125 + BP^2 (4 + (36992 BQ^2)/405) + (289 BQ^2 (324 + 1445 BQ^2))/6561 *)
```

Comment: Thanks again Bill, you are awesome. :) So, the steps that I need to follow are: 1. Use reduce, pass all the equations and desired variables to it. 2. Use the `//.` expression to put the reduced values inside the expression that we want to evaluate.

Comment: I have one question. :) Why is there an extra `PQ` inside `Reduce` when I want `AC` and `AP` to be expressed in terms of only `BQ` and `BP`? Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the results from `Reduce` they use `==`. If you look at the documentation for `ReplaceRepeated` or `//.` they use `->`. Then there is the issue of minus signs. Since `5*AC^4 + 4*AP^2` was all even powers I cheated just a bit and just used the results without having to worry about powers of -1. Does that make sense?

Comment: Try removing the `PQ` from `Reduce` and see what you get? I think you will get `PQ` in your results and that doesn't seem like what you wanted so I also solved for that and substituted that result into your expression to get rid of the `PQ`.

Comment: Thanks again Bill, now I understand it. `Reduce` gives us the relation between different variables so that we can substitute their values in the expression that we want to evaluate using `//.`. Am I right?

Comment: `Reduce` was probably written by one group of people with one set of ideas and methods. `Solve` was probably done by someone else with different ideas and methods. Your goal is to understand how to correctly use the important functions in MMA. Remember there are usually twelve different ways of doing anything in MMA and a few of those few people will ever really understand in depth.